# echoing PHP code from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am struggling with this a few hours now. So this is the thing. I want to display admin pages from database. The code is stored in table admin_pages column news. I want to get id by this function

```
function getID(){
    $id="";
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    } else {
        $id=1;
    }
}
```

& this one

```
function show_by_id($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    if(getID($id == 1)) {
    $content = "";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM admin_pages WHERE id='$id' ") or trigger_error('Problem occured!');
while($content = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo  $content['news'];
}}}
```

& Im calling it like this: `<?php show_by_id(getID())?>`

Now, I can't figure out why it is not working. It does not give back any error, but still ain't working. Please don't vote down, I really need this asap.

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work, enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that's the thing! Thanks a lot man

Comment: If you're happy with Joachim Isaksson's answer, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

`getID()` needs to return `$id` after calculating it;

```
function getID(){
    $id="";
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    } else {
        $id=1;
    }
    return $id;
}
```